# Why is node fetch not working (node-fetch) in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I'm trying to fetch data from a URL with fetch but it doesn't work. I imported node-fetch module by typing:

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
```

And here's where I use it:

```
async function getUrl(url) {
    let d = await fetch(url);
    let j = d.json();
    return j;
}

getUrl(myURL);
```

I also have the 'npm install node-fetch' to the terminal and it says there's no such file or directory.

Do you know where I am having the issue?

Comment: Can you please edit your answer to contain both the error from your code and the error from trying to install the package? Thanks.

Comment: it's an async function. Add await.

`console.log(await getUrl(myURL))`

Comment: Did you set up npm package using `npm init`?

Comment: Parsers in the fetch API is async. You need to `let j = await d.json();`

Comment: slebetman I forgot, thx for the reminder. However, my problem is still there.

Comment: It says no such file or directory for node-fetch when I type `npm i node-fetch`

Comment: That's the problem

Comment: So the problem is not that the library isn't working but you don't know how to install it?

Comment: I mean previously when I typed `npm i node-fetch` it worked. However this time it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Once `fetch` is imported this works (in browsers `fetch` is built-in):

```js
async function getUrl(url) {
    let d = await fetch(url);
    let j = await d.json();
    return j;
}

// example JSON API
const myURL = 'https://reqres.in/api/users';

// IIFE needed for demonstration purposes
(async function(){
  const data = await getUrl(myURL);
  console.log(data);
})()
```